# delphi how i update progressbar accurately according to captureconsoleoutput process

Tags: delphi

helo dear all i made an application on delphi 10.3 to comunicate with android using captureconsoleoutput pip process. how i update progressbar of application that count captureconsoleoutput process and update progressbar accurately. my code is

```
CaptureConsoleOutput(currentdir.Text+'\dat\adb -d '+com.text+' '+currentdir.Text+'\dat\loader\'+hisi.Text+'\config','',
        procedure(const Line: PAnsiChar)
        begin
            Memo2.Lines.Add(String(Line));
            progressbar1.StepIt;

        end
);
```

Comment: What is the output from the adb command?

Comment: Actual name of adb ie hisi-idt I rename it to adb its A python script which is converted to exe using auto py to exe and now I am send bootloader images to hisilicon vcom port. This command write bootloader images to phone and gives output with percentage complete in console mode. But how I display the actual progress of hidden console to vcl form progressbar

Comment: *Showing* what it does would be far more useful, because then suggestions might be able to be made as to how you could capture it and turn it into progress information